# Rust FnMut closure updates a var but doesn't stick

Tags: rust

I have this rust code where I am trying to implement observability. And, in my closure `add_foo_listener` I simply update the `called` variable and then assert it it's called.

This code compiles, and the closure is invoked, as is evidenced by the `println`, but the `called` variable doesn't stick. Everything I read says I should be using `FnMut` which, I believe I am. But, I don't understand why this boolean isn't being updated

```rust
    #[derive(Debug, Clone, Hash, PartialEq, Eq)]
    struct Foo {
        baz: u32
    }
    struct Holder {
        pub foo_observers: Vec<Box<dyn FnMut(Foo)>>,
    }

    impl Holder {

        pub fn add_foo_listener<CB: 'static + FnMut(Foo) + FnMut(Foo)>(&mut self, on_foo: CB) -> &mut Self {
            self.foo_observers.push(Box::new(on_foo));
            self
        }

        pub fn notify_foo_event(&mut self, foo: Foo) -> &mut Self {
            self.foo_observers
                .iter_mut()
                .for_each(|notify| notify(foo.clone()));
            self
        }
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_foo() -> Result<(), String> {
        let mut holder = Holder{
            foo_observers: Vec::new()
        };
        let mut called: bool = false;
        let foo = Foo{
            baz : 10
        };

        holder.add_foo_listener( move |f: Foo| {
            assert_eq!(f,foo);
            println!("Listener called");
            called = true;
        }).notify_foo_event(foo);
        assert!(called); // called is still false
        Ok(())
    }
```

Output:

```
---- notifier::test::test_foo stdout ----
Listener called
thread 'notifier::test::test_foo' panicked at 'assertion failed: called', foo.rs
assert!(called); 
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Comment: Copy/pasting this code into the playground doesn't compile, because `called` is moved into the closure, and so can't be used in the `assert` later

Comment: @cameron1024: You can remove the `assert_eq!()` from the closure, that is not essential for the question, and you'll get the announced behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the closure, you are using the `move` keyword: this means that all the captured values are *moved* into the closure.

A non-`Copy` value would be unusable after the closure creation, but your `called` is of type `bool` that is `Copy`. This means that the closure has copy of called while your `test_foo()` has another copy. They are disconnected, so if you modify one the other will notice nothing.

If you want to use the same value you have to somehow capture in the closure a reference to the original value. If the closure function is simple you can just remove the `move`, but if it is more complex that may not be possible, then you can capture a reference explicitly:

```
let rcalled = &mut called;
holder.add_foo_listener(
    move |f: Foo| {
        println!("Listener called");
        *rcalled = true;
    }
).notify_foo_event(foo);
```

Unfortunately, this does not compile because this closure now holds a reference to a local variable, that makes it no `'static`, which is required by `add_foo_listener()`.

To get a reference-like value that is `'static` you can use the Rust big-gun: `Arc<RefCell<T>>`. Although in your case, since it is a `Copy` value, you can use the simpler `Arc<Cell<T>>`:

```
let called = Arc::new(Cell::new(false));
holder.add_foo_listener({
    let called = called.clone();
    move |f: Foo| {
        println!("Listener called");
        called.set(true);
    }
}).notify_foo_event(foo);
assert!(called.get()); // called is now true
```

Comment: There's no point in `Arc<Cell<T>>`. You're just losing performance by atomic operations, and not even gaining future-proof. Use either `Rc<Cell<T>>` or `Arc<AtomicBool>`.